# c# Refactor switch statement with null check

Tags: c#, switch-statement, refactoring

I am just having a bit of trouble with a couple of switch statements really and i feel there is a much better way of achieving the end goal.

So essentially i am passing in viewmodel into a method. The method first retrieves the object the viewmodel relates to from the database, then a switch statement does a null check on a particular property. Based on that result, another switch statement does another null check on the view model. At each point values are assigned to the object from the database, then a database update happens at the end.

Here is the code

```
        public async Task UpdateContractWithRepository(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Get the contract from db
        Contract contract = GetContract(viewModel.Id);

        switch (viewModel.RepositoryId == null)
        {
            case true:
                switch (contract.RepositoryId == null)
                {
                    case true:
                        // nothing to do
                        // no change
                        break;
                    case false:
                        // Unassign Repository
                        UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);

                        // Update properties
                        contract.RepositoryId = null;
                        contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case false:
                switch (contract.RepositoryId == null)
                {
                    case true:
                        // assign repository
                        UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

                        // Get repository
                        Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

                        // Update properties
                        contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
                        contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
                        break;
                    case false:
                        // assign repository
                        UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

                        // Get repository
                        Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

                        // Update properties
                        contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
                        contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
                        break;
                }
                break;

        }

        UpdateContract(contract);
    }
```

I'm thinking i could probably do away with the switch statements and use if statements instead, there would still be some nesting from what i can tell. Just wondered if anyone had any suggestions.

I've had a look at refactoring switch statements on here, but they don't really seem to cover null checks.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using switch statements for simple if/then/else constuctions? Would it not be better to just switch to if statements? 
Also if you are doing a lot of work in a switch is seems better to put in their own (private) methods.

Comment: You second switch statement looks like it has a bug in it... both true and false execute the same code...

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen aren't c# switches faster executing then if/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole code can be simplified if you just take out two bools:

```
bool IsVMRepoNull = viewModel.RepositoryId == null;
bool IsContractRepoNull = contract.RepositoryId == null;

if(IsVMRepoNull && !IsContractRepoNull )
{
  UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);

 // Update properties
  contract.RepositoryId = null;
  contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
}
else if(!IsVMRepoNull)
{
  UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

  // Get repository
  Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

  // Update properties
  contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
  contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure where you are stuck - but replacing the switches with `if`/`else` is almost as simply as replacing `switch` with `if`. Here's the transformed code:

```
public async Task UpdateContractWithRepository(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Get the contract from db
    Contract contract = GetContract(viewModel.Id);

    if (viewModel.RepositoryId == null)
    {
        if (contract.RepositoryId == null)
        {
            // nothing to do
            // no change
        } else {
            // Unassign Repository
            UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);

            // Update properties
            contract.RepositoryId = null;
            contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
        }
    } else {
        if (contract.RepositoryId == null)
        {
            // assign repository
            UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

            // Get repository
            Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

            // Update properties
            contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
            contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
        } else {

            // assign repository
            UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

            // Get repository
            Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

            // Update properties
            contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
            contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
        }
    }

    UpdateContract(contract);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not necessary to do it so complicated.
Try this I think that it do same work:

```
public async Task UpdateContractWithRepository(ViewModel viewModel){
        Contract contract = GetContract(viewModel.Id);

        if (viewModel.RepositoryId == null)
        {
            if(contract.RepositoryId != null){
                UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);
                contract.RepositoryId = null;
                contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (contract.RepositoryId == null)
            {
                UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);
                Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);
                contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
                contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);
                Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);
                contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
                contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
            }
        }
        UpdateContract(contract);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really use `if....else if` with bool conditions. You can make it more readable with meaningful variable-names:

```
public async Task UpdateContractWithRepository(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Get the contract from db
    Contract contract = GetContract(viewModel.Id);

    bool modelRepositoryKnown = viewModel.RepositoryId != null;
    bool contractRepositoryKnown = contract.RepositoryId != null;

    if (modelRepositoryKnown)
    {
        if (contractRepositoryKnown)
        {
            // assign repository
            UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

            // Get repository
            Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

            // Update properties
            contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
            contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
        }
        else
        {
            // assign repository
            UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);

            // Get repository
            Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);

            // Update properties
            contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
            contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
        }
    }
    else if(contractRepositoryKnown)  // Model-Repository unknown but Contract-Repository Known
    {
        // Unassign Repository
        UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);

        // Update properties
        contract.RepositoryId = null;
        contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
        break;
    }
    UpdateContract(contract);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by combining your nested switch conditions into an if else statements which uses multiple conditions.

```
if(viewModel.RepositoryId == null && !contract.RepositoryId)
{
    // Unassign Repository
    UpdateRepositoryAssignment(contract.RepositoryId, false);
    // Update properties
    contract.RepositoryId = null;
    contract.ConsumedUnits = null;
}
else if(!viewModel.RepositryId && contract.RepositoryId == null)
{
    // assign repository
    UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);
    // Get repository
    Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);
    // Update properties
    contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
    contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
} 
else if(!viewModel.RepositryId && !contract.RepositoryId == null)
{
    // assign repository
    UpdateRepositoryAssignment(viewModel.RepositoryId, true);
    // Get repository
    Repository repository = GetRepository(viewModel.RepositoryId);
    // Update properties
    contract.RepositoryId = repository.Id;
    contract.ConsumedUnits = repository.Units;
}
```